# Set accept and contentType to json by default for restassured

Tags: java, rest-assured

How could I set the accept and contentType to json projectwide in my rest tests?

```
    given()
        .accept(ContentType.JSON)
        .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
```

This will reduce quite some repetitive code

Comment: why not just create a method givenJSON() that sets those and call that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RestAssured.requestSpecification = new RequestSpecBuilder()
        .setContentType(ContentType.JSON)
        .setAccept(ContentType.JSON)
        .build();
```